# Converting to PDF using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pdf

I am working in QGIS 2.18.18. I have converted maps into PDF in a couple of prior projects, but the current map I am working on will not complete all the layers in the finished PDF.  Specifically, the OSM layer.  The OSM layer is visible across the bottom of the PDF map and barely makes it half way up.

What could be causing this??

Comment: It might be a memory issue, does the issue persist if you only print a smaller portion of the map?

Comment: I think you may be right. I thought that originally, but I sent the specs of my computer to someone and they said it should be fine.  I think the OSM layer is just too large for it to process maybe?  I just tried creating a PDF of a smaller size (Ansi C) instead of an E size and it filled almost the whole map, but it still wasn't complete.